# How to fix the headline row in a table using css?

Tags: html, css

I  made a table with no borders in the columns, and I gave 1px border only in the rows.

I have used the 'border collapsed' property and then I have given all the rows a border of 1 px.

However my problem is that the row of the headlines is a bit longer then the rest of the table?

Does anyone know how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

**html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>web programming project 2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="exe2CSS1.css">
<body>


<table class=outlined>
<tr id=headline>
<th class=side>Item</th>
<th class=side>Manufacturer</th>
<th class=side>Size</th>
<th class=center>Unit Price</th>
<th class=center>Quantity</th>
<th class=center>Total Price</th>
</tr>

<tr  class=firstCol>
<td class=side>Corn Flakes</td>
<td class=side>Kellogg's</td>
<td class=side>18 0z</td>
<td class=center>2.5</td>
<td class=center>1</td>
<td class=center>2.5</td>
</tr>


<tr class=secondCol>
<td class=side>Solid White Tuna</td>
<td class=side>Starkist</td>
<td class=side>5 oz</td>
<td class=center>2.79</td>
<td class=center>2</td>
<td class=center>5.58</td>
</tr>


</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**css code:**

```
.outlined
{
font:13px Tahoma;
width: 75%;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
border: 1px solid white;
}

.secondCol{
background-color: #eeeff2
}

.firstCol{
background-color: #dfe1e7
}

.center{
text-align: center;
}

.side{
text-align: left
}

#headline{
background-color: #687291;
color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! the closing </tr> fixed my problem! :-)))

Comment: You can then valid an answer

Comment: How should I do that ?

Comment: See the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) : "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes around the attributes value and you missed a closing `</th>` on the first row for "Total Price" (you have a `<th>` instead)

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zp35V/)**

```
<tr id="headline">
    <th class="side">Item</th>
    <th class="side">Manufacturer</th>
    <th class="side">Size</th>
    <th class="center">Unit Price</th>
    <th class="center">Quantity</th>
    <th class="center">Total Price</th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi your last  tag is not closed properly "`<th class=center>Total Price<th>`"